# Shell script find command for matching file names with one or the other word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04, busybox

I am looking for a command for bash shell script to find the list of files in a directory whose names start with either WordA or WordB and end with digits.

I have this command with `WordA` and duplicating the same code with `WordB`.

```
find /log/ -name 'WordA*[[:digit:]]'
```

I tried putting Or condition in various formats such as `(WordA|WordB)`, `[WordA|WordB]`, `[(WordA)|(WordB)]`, `[(WordA)||(WordB)]` to match `WordA` or `WordB` followed by digits.

None of them worked.

Comment: Just run two find commands ...  `find /log/ -name 'WordA*[[:digit:]]'` then run `find /log/ -name 'WordB*[[:digit:]]'`.

Comment: Mentioned 2 in the question for simplicity. Actually, I have to match for 4 words or so. Don't want to paste it 4 times really considering maintenance perspective.

Comment: @bjskishore123: See if my answer helped

Comment: @Inian: It helped but doesn't work on busybox

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `-regextype` supported in `find` command, in the case used the `posix-extended` type and do

```
-regextype type
      Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex 
      tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented  
      types  are  emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic, 
      posix-egrep and posix-extended.
```

So your command should be

```
find /log/ -regextype posix-extended -regex './(WordA|WordB)([[:digit:]]+)$'
```

Answer (score 2):

In the find man page, under header Expressions, you'll find (no pun intended) the following

> Operators
>
> Operators join together the other items within  the  expression.
>   They include for example -o (meaning logical OR) and -a (meaning
>   logical AND).  Where an operator is missing, -a is assumed.

Thus the answer to your problem appears to be

```
 find /log/ -name 'WordA*[[:digit:]]' -o 'WordB*[[:digit:]]'
```